# How to remove a word from a CString

Tags: c++, c++11, c-strings

I have the following CString which stores the path of a file how can I remove the last three chars of the Cstring AuthFile in order to change the file name

```
        CString AuthFile = m_strFileName;
        
// Remove last three charters of CString and replace with "auth" 
        AuthFile.Append("auth");
```

Comment: If you mean the Microsoft's `CString`, then e.g. `AuthFile.Truncate(AuthFile.GetLenth() - 3)`. Or `AuthFile.Delete(AuthFile.GetLenth() - 3, 3)`

Comment: We need clarity here. The "c-strings" tag refers to null-terminated C-style character arrays. As @Igor has suggested, it looks like you are using the MFC/ATL `CString` class. Also, do you always want to remove the **last 3** characters, or are you actually looking to change a file extension?